# How to access to a key of a result of .value() queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this queryset:

```
p = RespuestaPreguntaSeleccionMultiple.objects.all().values('respuesta').annotate(Count('respuesta'))
```

The result is this:

```
[{'respuesta__count': 2, 'respuesta': u'Una vez'}]
```

I need to access only to `respuesta__count` or `respuesta` key, I mean, only get `2` or `"Una vez"` for finally pass it to the template, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need iterate over the result list:

```
p = RespuestaPreguntaSeleccionMultiple.objects.all().values('respuesta').annotate(Count('respuesta'))

for item in p:
    item['respuesta__count']  # This will return 2
    item['respuesta']  # This will return 'Una vez'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
p = RespuestaPreguntaSeleccionMultiple.objects.all().values_list(
    'respuesta').annotate(Count('respuesta'))
```

It'll return the values as `[('Una vez', 2)]`

Edit:

So it seems like you want two lists for each value. If that's the case then you could do this:

```
p = RespuestaPreguntaSeleccionMultiple.objects.all().values_list(
    'respuesta').annotate(Count('respuesta'))
respuesta_set, counts = zip(*p)
```

In this case `respuesta_set` will be equal to `['Una vez']` and `counts` will be equal to `[2]`.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to print only "Una vez" or "2" by separate?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you give an example of how you want to use it?

Comment: in resume, I have to show a bar graphic of a result of a poll, for that I need to count how many times there are an specific result, so in the axe Y I need to print 'Una vez' and inthe axe X show "2" for that, I need to print each key by separate

Comment: I edited the answer to what I think you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, I found the solution as someone told here, just iterate the result list.